# Styling a radio button inside a form

Tags: css, html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to styling a form in which I have got a radio button. I want to change the default view of the radio button and  add background image for the radio button and for the check image. Moreover I want to place my form in the center of the screen and highlighted with a line. My code is here  in jsfiddle:

```
           <style>
                form{
                    font-size: 200%;
                    font-family: "Courier New", Monospace;
                    display: inline-block;
                    align: middle;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-weight: bold; 
                     background-size: 20px; 
                }     

                input[type="radio"] {
                      width: 26px;
                      height: 26px;
                      background: url(check.png) no-repeat;

                }

                </style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrathan/q1mnq2os/2/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/chrathan/q1mnq2os/2/)

How can I perform those operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
form{
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: "Courier New", Monospace;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold; 
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 20px; 
}     

input[type="radio"] {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none
}
label{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40px
}
label:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after{
    background: red; /*add your background image here*/
}
```

```html
<form class = "form"  action="action2.php"  method="post">
    
    <a href=' .$user. ' style=\"text-decoration:none;\"> "' .$user. '" </a><br><br>
    <p>
        <input   type="radio" name="classif" id="C1" value="true" checked="checked" hidden />
        <label for="C1">FASHION</label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="classif" id="C2" value="false" hidden />
        <label for="C2"> NON FASHION </label>
    
        <input type="hidden" name="imageName" value="' . $line . '">
    </p>
    
    <input   type="submit"   value="submit"  />
    </form>;
```

Comment: How can I add my image in the last brackets?

Comment: you  can use `form p:nth-last-of-type  input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after{
    background: red; /*add your background image here*/
}` or just give his parent a class

Comment: I tried to add the proposed input. I updated my jsfiddle. I couldn't add the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Centering form:

Remove

```
display:inline-block
```

and add:

```
margin:0 auto
```

to form.

[**Updated jsfiddle is here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/q1mnq2os/1/)

[This is a nice link for styling radio button.](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)